# Make 100 sprites from single sprite object

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am making game in cocos2D , in that i am using TMX map in that. Now in that , I put stars as score, player has to collect the stars , so that its score will increase.

My problem is i want to run repeat forever action on every sprite. I don't add that sprite to the tile map but i just make one extra layer and in that, i put tiles with star property.

Now, Where i add this tile map, at that time i check all tiles in the meta layer with star property and i want to put star image there.

My question is, As i don't know the number of tiles with the star property, so we can't make that much object array of CCSprite. And I know that we can't add one CCsprite object in scene twice.

How can i proceed to this problem? 
Any kind of help will be appreciated..

Comment: for each star tile create a star sprite and add it to the array. Where's the problem in that?

Comment: If i make star sprite for each star tile, than i have to make array of n CCSprite object right? N I don't know how many star will be there.

Comment: yeah so? every time you need a new star, create it and add it to the array. You don't need to know the number of stars in advance, plus even that is simple if you enumerate all tiles and count the star tiles.